# How do I perform a Bartlett test with two continuous variables?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I want to test homogeneity of variance on the data:

```
structure(list(Year = 1992:2010, Incidence = c(0.086, 0.109, 
0.079, 0.142, 0.114, 0.156, 0.137, 0.181, 0.152, 0.162, 0.204, 
0.246, 0.208, 0.227, 0.246, 0.274, 0.272, 0.278, 0.29), Temperature = c(26.8, 
27, 27.7, 27, 28, 28.3, 28, 28.5, 28.3, 28.4, 28.1, 27.6, 29.2, 
27.3, 27.1, 28.1, 28.8, 27.7, 28.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

but I don't know how to do this using the Bartlett test. I keep getting the error message:

```
> "Error in bartlett.test.default(model$residuals, CC$Year) :    there
> must be at least 2 observations in each group"
```

I understand that it wants a factor group but I have been assured I can complete a Bartlett test for this sort of data? Is there another test I can do instead?

I have tried:

```r
bartlett.test(CC$Incidence ~ CC$Temperature)
bartlett.test(CC$Incidence, CC$Temperature)
```

I have also tried:

```r
bartlett.test(CC$Incidence)
```

But this gives the error message :

```
> "Error in bartlett.test.default(CC$Incidence) :    argument "g" is
> missing, with no default"
```

Comment: Can you please include your data in a code block in the question - ideally using `dput(data)` - rather than as an image? It makes it much easier for other people to help

Comment: I have added the data using dput(data), is this what you mean?

Comment: group years into two groups before and after 2000